# Test the hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, statistical-inference

A new medicine was invented to threat a serious disease. An experiment on $5000$ women and $4000$ men showed that the mean of effect is $10.2$ in women group and $10$ in men group. If samples were drawn down from the normal population with variance $3$, test on $10$% level significance a hypothesis that the effect for women is significantly more than for men.

We assume that samples are independent. Denote $\xi_1 \sim N(a_1,3)$ - women results, $\xi_2 \sim N(a_1,3)$- men results. I used t-test with
$$ H_0: a_1=a_2,$$
$$ H_1: a_1> a_2.$$

Test statistic:
$$t= \frac{10.2-10}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{\frac{1}{5000}+\frac{1}{4000}}} \approx 5.44$$

As samples drawn from normal distribution, $t \sim N(0,1),$ then
$$A_{crit} = [z_{1-\alpha},+\infty) \approx [1.282, +\infty)$$

So we reject a null-hypothesis in favour to alternative.
Is this a correct solution?

Comment: The only thing I would change in this is to call the test statistic $Z$ not $t.$